# query with join for ManyToMany relation

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Please help me with query!!!
I have 2 entity with relation ManyToMany.

```
@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String headName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "departmentsList")
    private List<Lector> lectorsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
public class Lector {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Degree degree;

    private Integer salary;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Department> departmentsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to get one Department wiht list Lector

```
public Department findOne(Long id){
        try {
            Department department = (Department) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                    "select * from Department d where d.Id = ? ", new Object[] { id },
                    new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Department.class));

            System.out.println(department);

            return department;


        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException notExist) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But this query returned empty "lectorsList"
What query i need to use?

Comment: You should be using spring-data-jpa (or Hibernate). Right now you're just querying what is in the `department` table. JdbcTemplate doesn't care nor know about the `@ManyToMany`, it just executes SQL and maps it to an object of the provided type.